# spryassets click event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, spry

I have the following in my page,

This is a spryasset. This has 3 tabs.[image]

When I click "reviews" it shows reviews, if "more" then it shows more.

My question is,

### How to listen to this "CLICK" event on a spryasset tab in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that spryasset produces `li` for each tab you could do this:

```
$('#tabs li:eq(2)').on('click', function() {
  // your code here
});
```

Update:

The `:eq(2)` will return the 3rd (starting from 0) list element that is a child of some element with id=tabs.   For more information on the :eq selector check out the jquery docs  http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: What is eq(2)? Can you explain whats going on?. Forgive my curiosity.

Comment: @beck03076 Sure thing.. I updated the answer.  The jquery docs are great and for a full list of selectors check out this link http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Let me take your lead and come back if I win. Thanks.

Comment: If you are a female, I would marry you. If you are not one, I would still marry you. Thanks a lot. It worked so beautifully.

Comment: I'm a dude so I'll happily accept the checkmark and a voteup in lieu of a marriage proposal!